# PSQL - Iterate over table and return results as table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, recursive-query, sql-function

Working on a table with columns  
**some_id**, **some_parent_id**, **some_param**.

I need to create a procedure or function that accept some_id as input and searches for its parent row. 
When parent row is found, it will search again for parent row of that row... and so on...until parent row is null. 
Function should returns all entries found during iteration.

[image]

So in this case if a function is called with value 3 it will return rows 2 and 1 and stop there cause some_parent_id is null

This is my attempt at storing results in temp table but all i get is NULL. What am I missing?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function(
    input_id int) 
RETURNS TABLE(
    r_id int,
    r_parent_id int,
    r_param int,
) AS $$
    DECLARE
        temp_table record;
        search_id int;
    begin
        search_id := input_id;
        for temp_table in (
            select some_id, some_parent_id, some_param FROM mytable where some_id = search_id)
        loop 
            search_id := temp_table.some_parent_id;
            return next;    
        end loop;
        return;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select * from  my_function (3754);
```

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses a recursive query instead of a loop:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select some_id, some_parent_id, some_param 
    from mytable 
    where some_id = input_id 
    union all
    select t.some_id, t.some_parent_id, t.some_param
    from mytable t
    inner join cte c on t.some_id = c.some_parent_id
)
select * from cte
```

You can use this query in your function as follows:

```
create or replace function my_function(input_id int) 
returns table(
    r_id int,
    r_parent_id int,
    r_param text
) as $$
with recursive cte as (
    select some_id, some_parent_id, some_param 
    from mytable 
    where some_id = input_id 
    union all
    select t.some_id, t.some_parent_id, t.some_param
    from mytable t
    inner join cte c on t.some_id = c.some_parent_id
)
select * from cte
$$
language sql;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ooKnuCjEmSbVxawnrdQ825/1)** with your sample data:

```
select * from my_function(2);

| r_id | r_parent_id | r_param |
| ---- | ----------- | ------- |
| 2    | 1           | value2  |
| 1    |             | value1  |
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) yeah that makes sense